# Block Sync Progress

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, fast-sync

There is no block number listed like others I've seen. At first thought it was processed but that number is impossible? Also running eth.syncing doesn't work since blockchain is not yet fully installed!

[image: Current Progress]

Comment: Are you using geth or eth?